# will_paginate with huge margin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have just a couple of months of Rails experience and I'm using will_paginate for the first time.

I'm using it in a table foot and I felt really strange that it took a huge height. I inspected it and noticed that it insert elements of 20px margin. Is this the expected behavior? Am I doing something wrong?

If I am not doing it wrong, could you advice on how could I stylish it? I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3 with the [bootstrap-will_paginate gem](https://github.com/yrgoldteeth/bootstrap-will_paginate) (tried  [will_paginate-bootstrap](https://github.com/nickpad/will_paginate-bootstrap) as well). I have reduced this huge margin but it seems awkward to me yet. Maybe centering it would help. I have tried to center without success. Any tips on that?

Comment: have you looked at kaminari? you can see a video here http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari and here is the gem site https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari. I have used it many times with Twitter Bootstrap 3 and it never gives me any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty late response but since I had the same question...

I used Firebug to figure out which CSS class was used to style pagination and it was `pagination` (go figure).  Then I just needed to override the CSS in my custom file to tighten up the margin:

```
/* override will-paginate margins */
.pagination {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I feel the approach is a bit brittle because I am depending on how the gem developers manage CSS but I can't think of a better approach.

Comment: Thanks! I can't check it as I'm not using Rails at least for now but I accepted the answer as you took the time to answer it!

Comment: Sorry it wasn't more timely for you.  Thanks for the support.

Comment: This worked for me, although I preferred using 0px for top and bottom margin.